# Inconsistent accessibility: field type is less accessible

Tags: c#, list, xna, collision-detection

I have 2 classes that references a list inside the main game function. Classes Block and MovingPlatform both have a list that holds all the objects.

```
public List<Block> Blocks;
public List<MovingPlatform> Platforms;
```

I also have a Collision Manager class which uses the 2 lists to see if platforms is colliding with a block and then make platforms go another direction.

I then transfer over the lists to the class Collision Manager:

```
public class Collision_Manager
{
    Game1 game1;

    public void Initialize(Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = new Game1();
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = game1;

        for (int i = 0; i < game1.Blocks.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle BlockBounds = new Rectangle(
                (int)game1.Blocks[i].Position.X, 
                (int)game1.Blocks[i].Position.Y, 
                game1.Blocks[i].Texture.Width, 
                game1.Blocks[i].Texture.Height);

            Rectangle top = new Rectangle((int)BlockBounds.X + 5, (int)BlockBounds.Y - 10, BlockBounds.Width - 10, 10);
            Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle((int)BlockBounds.X + 5, (int)BlockBounds.Y + BlockBounds.Height, BlockBounds.Width - 10, 10);
            Rectangle left = new Rectangle((int)BlockBounds.X - 10, (int)BlockBounds.Y + 5, 10, BlockBounds.Height - 10);
            Rectangle right = new Rectangle((int)BlockBounds.X + BlockBounds.Width, (int)BlockBounds.Y + 5, 10, BlockBounds.Height - 10);

            for (int b = 0; b < game1.Platforms.Count; b++)
            {
                Rectangle PlatformBounds = new Rectangle(
                (int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.X,
                (int)game1.Platforms[i].Position.Y,
                game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Width,
                game1.Platforms[i].Texture.Height);

                if (top.Intersects(new Rectangle(PlatformBounds.X, PlatformBounds.Y, PlatformBounds.Width, PlatformBounds.Height)) && game1.Blocks[i].BlockState == 3)
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = false;
                }

                if (bottom.Intersects(new Rectangle(PlatformBounds.X, PlatformBounds.Y, PlatformBounds.Width, PlatformBounds.Height)) && game1.Blocks[i].BlockState == 3)
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = true;
                }

                if (left.Intersects(new Rectangle(PlatformBounds.X, PlatformBounds.Y, PlatformBounds.Width, PlatformBounds.Height)) && game1.Blocks[i].BlockState == 3)
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = false;
                }

                if (right.Intersects(new Rectangle(PlatformBounds.X, PlatformBounds.Y, PlatformBounds.Width, PlatformBounds.Height)) && game1.Blocks[i].BlockState == 3)
                {
                    game1.Platforms[i].Thing = true ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I am getting the error: `Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Game.Block>' is less accessible than field 'Game.Game1.Blocks'`

`Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Game.MovingPlatform>' is less accessible than field 'Game.Game1.Platforms'`

**How do I fix my problem?**

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: It does not allow me to debug the game, it will say do you want to use last version.

Comment: But it still should tell you at which line in the code the error happens...

Comment: Make everything public, then revert them back to their previous accessibility modifiers until the error pops up again

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Perhaps your class `Game.Block` declared as internal.

Comment: You need make Block and Platforms internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Block and Platform classes must be public because you use them in public fields.
Or you can use the same or a lower accessor for the property as the one you use in your class.
For example if your class is declared internal use also internal for your field.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes `Block` and `MovingPlatform` have lesser access than your `public` fields `List<Block> Blocks` and `List<MovingPlatform> Platforms`.

You probably haven't defined any access specifiers with your classes `Block` and `MovingPlatform`, so they are considered `internal` by default, which is less accessible then public.

You can fix the issue by making those classes as `public` or you can have your fields marked as `internal`. You should decided your access to properties/classes according to your requirement. You may see [Access Modifiers (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)